# web2py - mostrar valor da variável com dados dum arquivo.csv na view

Tags: python, pandas, web2py

Tenho um projeto do framework web2py chamado ucsalPY com uma aplication denominada ucsal.

O caminho da aplicação é:

```
ucsalPY/application/ucsal (/controllers, /models, /views)
```

No controller default.py criei o método:

```
nomes={"nome": ['Pedro', 'Tiago', 'Joao']}

index():
return nomes
```

e na view index.html eu leio `{{=nomes}}`, desta forma funciona.

Eu tentei importar o pandas para ler o arquivo csv e retornar no index, mas o browser mostra internal erro quando eu abro `localhost:8000/ucsal/default/index`.

Inseri a linha `import pandas as pd` ou no model ou no controller e só esta linha já dá o erro.

Como eu mostro dados de qualquer fonte (db ou arquivo) numa view? Não sei se tenho que colocar alguma coisa no models. Só lembrando que tenho os arquivos db.py e menu.py em ucsal/models.

o erro quando eu importo pandas nomodel é:

at 0x0000000004C4A270, file "C:\Users\USUARIO\workspacePython\ucsalPI\applications\ucsal\models\db.py", line 7>

Já quando importo no controller é:

at 0x0000000009C02810, file "C:\Users\USUARIO\workspacePython\ucsalPI\applications\ucsal\controllers/default.py", line 6>

Comment: Como é o erro que aparece ao qual está se referindo? Tem o pandas instalado no python que está usando?

Comment: @Marlysson editei a pergunta e coloquei mais detalhes.